# Spring data CrudRepository findBy relationships

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to select all Foo entities that have any Bars that have status new.

Here's what I tried:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO")
class Foo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Bar> bars;

   //...
}



public interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository<Foo, Long> {


    @Query("select m from Foo f where f.bars.status = 'NEW' ")
    public Page<Foo> findByBarStatus(Pageable pageable);

}
```

But I get :

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

I also tried writing join statement instead:

```
select f from Foo f inner join f.bars b where b.status = 'NEW'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT f FROM Foo AS f JOIN f.bars AS b WHERE b.status = 'NEW'
```

Comment: you forgot the 'AS's

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing something like this

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo")
private Set<Bar> bars;
```

Answer (score 1):

joining for one-to-many relationship can sometimes be tricky. (There is another answer doing it right, that you can refer to)

In this case, you may do it in reverse (assuming you have the relationship being bi-directional), by looking up from the `Bar` side:

```
select bar.foo from Bar bar where bar.status = 'NEW'
```

Comment: Actually I was also missing `@JoinColumn(name = "Bar")`

Comment: @Benedictus it is not necessarily "missing", as Hibernate can deduce column name (though the name may not be what you want)